# Spec creating tmp file on circleCI is failing

Tags: rspec, continuous-integration, circleci

I have rspec test which creates a tmp file and it is read in the test. CircleCI fails saying

```
Failure/Error: file_name = generate_csv_file(items)
 Errno::ENOENT:
   No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /home/ubuntu/project/tmp/batch_1443573588.csv
```

Comment: Is the TMPDIR environment variable set in your CircleCI environment? If you're not sure, ssh to a build instance and `echo $TMPDIR`. Also, please show your code that creates the temp file.

Answer (score 5):

CricleCi by default does not have [tmp directory](https://circleci.com/docs/missing-dir/) for rails projects.

Your options are to:

- use system /tmp
- add tmp to git repository
- add post checkout hook in circle.yml that will [create it](https://circleci.com/docs/missing-dir/)

Comment: Both links are broken now